# How can I set a 'null' value explicitly in an integer array element in C++?

Tags: c++

Like in Java, there's a way to set null values in array elements,

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[5];
```

In here, *arr* is an Integer array with size 5 and it contains null by default.

So can we do the same in C++?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238878/discussion-on-question-by-codosopher-how-can-i-set-null-value-explicitly-in-in).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, `Integer` is an object type, not a primitive type, so it's allowable to to set one to null.  C++ doesn't have equivalent object types.  A better analogue would be the following java:

```java
int[] arr = new int[5];
```

Here you have a primitive `int` type which can't be set to a null value.  In C++ it's the same thing.

The closest you can do is set all values to 0 or some other sentinel value.  Either that or create your own `Integer` type which I wouldn't advise.